# Python to Teradata date issue

Tags: python, sql, pandas, teradata, python-datetime

I have gone through many stackoverflow post regarding the issue, but nothing has provided a solution. I will give details of the problem:

**About the data :** I have a dataframe with 52 columns. 6 columns out of 52 have dates as data. 3 of the dates columns are empty, defined as `df.insert(5,"ACTIVE_DATE","")`,  since they are filled later manually  and 3 are filled with dates. The 3 filled columns are in the format DD/MM/YYYY.

**About the issue :** I have tried to upload the data to teradata using sqlalachemy and teradataml. The DB table has its own index and so its set as false. I am using the following connection method from sqlalchemy:

```
eng = sqlalchemy.create_engine('teradatasql://user:pass@host')
df.to_sql(name='Sales_DB',con=eng,if_exists='append',index=False,schema='sales')
```

But every time I get the same error :

> Caused by [Version 17.0.0.3] [Session 19245476] [Teradata Database] [Error 2666] Invalid date supplied for Sales_DB.CREATE_DATE.
> at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).formatDatabaseError TeradataConnection.go:1138
> at gosqldriver/teradatasql<

To resolve this I changed the date format and to understand the underlying problem to the teradata format of YYYY-MM-DD. That seemed to work for the 3 filled date columns but not for the **null** date columns. It seems that empty date value is not recognized by teradata. I tried using  `df.insert(5,"ACTIVE_DATE",None)`, but this doesn't work in teradata as well resulting in an error - Untraceable character.

**Question 1:** How can I successfully upload the df to teradata when 3 columns are empty? They cannot be filled by a place holder since they need to be sent out empty.

**Question 2:** Another DB has the dates with format DD/MM/YYYY and that seems to work without issues, though its not using python script. Can someone please explain why this doesn't work?

Thank you

Comment: When loading these empty dates into Teradata, are they truly empty in the dataframe `NaN` or are they blanks `""`? I would assume, but haven't tested, that a `NaN` dataframe value would convert automatically to a NULL date in Teradata without error. Also, as another direction towards a solution, are these columns in Teradata defined as `NOT NULL`?

Comment: Also, when performing ETL, sometimes it's easiest to just load into a table where most columns are just set as "VARCHAR(<whatever>)"  to allow loading of not-so-perfect data. After that "load" table is loaded a stored procedure, or subsequent SQL statement is sent to the DB to load that data into the target table performing whatever transformations are needed to make it clean. That may be an easier option rather than trying to divine what python and sqlalchemy are doing under the hood.

Comment: Generally sqlalchemy expects/returns Python `None` for database `NULL`.  What does "doesn't work" mean? Same error or different error? If your "dates" are being supplied to the database as strings, then conversion may depend on the FORMAT associated with the target column (which may be defaulted to a system setting or explicitly stated.

Comment: @Fred I get another error - Untraceable character for None. The Dates are already defined in the Teradata table as Dates and as such i can't change it.

Comment: @JNevill The columns don't have `NOT NULL` defined. The empty dates in teradata look likes blanks `""` as they are do not say `NULL` in the DB columns. I do not have the rights to create a table but only to load the data to that table.

Comment: I can't recall ever seeing that error. Does it specifically call out ACTIVE_DATE as the issue or could it be a different column? Maybe post a new question - formatting and `None` address your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I am not answering this too late, but I think the issue may be Teradata has no concept of Python's None. If you try and insert/update a value in Teradata with Python's None, you may hit a similar issue. It also looks like your column is Datetime, so you cannot insert a blank string ("") to it:

```
INSERT INTO DB.TBL (DATE_FIELD, KEY_FIELD) VALUES (None, 3); -- Will produce a Syntax error

INSERT INTO DB.TBL (DATE_FIELD, KEY_FIELD) VALUES ("",3); -- Will produce a coltype error
```

Try and have the default value for your date be either NULL or 1900-01-01 00:00:01 - Teradata understands this.

```
df.insert(5,"ACTIVE_DATE","1900-01-01 00:00:01")
df.insert(5,"ACTIVE_DATE","NULL")
```